# How to display the legend over another Axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As shown in the following example, the legend for the left Axes is always occluded by the right Axes, even if I change its zorder and the clip_on property. However, the legend for the right Axes is displayed over the left Axes by default (tested in Matplotlib 3.1.3).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0], label='Line 1')
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], label='Line 2')
legend1 = ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 0.9), loc='upper right')
legend1.set_zorder(100)
legend1.set_clip_on(False)
legend2 = ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.8), loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transFigure.inverted()` transformation to adjust the positioning of the legends explicitly in the figure space. By setting the `bbox_to_anchor` and `transform` properties for each legend, you can control their placement relative to the axes and ensure they are displayed over the other axes as desired. Adjust the anchor coordinates as needed for your specific layout.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0], label='Line 1')
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], label='Line 2')

# Get the figure transformation
fig_trans = fig.transFigure.inverted()
 
legend1 = ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 0.9), loc='upper right')
legend1.set_bbox_to_anchor((1.15, 0.9))
legend1.set_transform(fig_trans)
 
legend2 = ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.8), loc='upper right')
legend2.set_bbox_to_anchor((0.2, 0.8))
legend2.set_transform(fig_trans)

plt.show()
```

Here is the sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't solve the problem. If you place the legend1 at (1.4, 0.9), it is still occluded by the right axes. I guess that why you need to change its location leftward. I put the legend in its original coordinates just to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding `figsize`

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(6, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0], label='Line 1')
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], label='Line 2')
legend1 = ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 0.9), loc='upper right')
legend2 = ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.8), loc='upper right')
legend1.set_zorder(2)  
legend2.set_zorder(1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output plot:]

Comment: Could you tell how is this better than OP's figure?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib could do a pretty decent job, if left on its own.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0], label='Line 1')
ax2.plot([0, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], label='Line 2')
legend1 = ax1.legend()
legend2 = ax2.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I put the legend at these particular locations just to demonstrate the issue, i.e., legend2 can float over the two axes, but legend1 will be occluded by ax2. I don't know why.

Comment: @herrlich10 If what you want is to demonstrate an issue, why don't you simply open [an issue on Matplotlib's github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues)?

Comment: My real purpose is to make a figure and put the two legends at the exact location as in my demo (for certain reasons unrelated here). Both of them should be visible, of course. Then I encountered the situation described above,  and I'm uncertain whether it's genuinely a bug or a challenge that can be resolved by some brilliant code. But you're right, maybe it is just a bug and I should open an issue at github. Thanks!